# Can't access labels in a custom cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController and a TableViewController on the storyboard.
The TableViewController has a custom cell with a label on it. Custom cell has its own class CompanyTableViewCell.swift:

```
import UIKit
class CompanyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var companyName : UILabel

    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        println("Cell's initialised")
    }

    ... // other default cell methods
}
```

In my TableViewController I have methods:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerClass(CompanyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CompanyCell")     
    println("Cell's registered")
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CompanyCell") as CompanyTableViewCell        
    println(cell.companyName)
    cell.companyName.text = "Company name"    
    return cell
}
```

When I run the code, **if the TableViewController is marked as initial view controller** it runs ok and the text of the label on my custom cell is being changed successfully. I can see bunch of cells with `Company name`.

But when I assign initial view controller property to the ViewController, and trying to access the TableViewController from it as (the ViewController has a button which runs searchByName action):

```
// ViewController.swift
@IBAction func searchByName(sender : UIButton) {
    var vc = SearchTableViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain) 
    vc.companies = self.companies
    self.showViewController(vc, sender: self)
}
```

I've got app crush on `cell.companyName.text = "Company name"` string with error: **fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None**. On the previous string `println(cell.companyName)` prints nil to console, although in console I see that cell class was registered and cell object was initialised.

The question is how to assign text to the label, what I've forgotten? And why it works in the first case but not in the second. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@IBOutlet var companyName : UILabel` is an outlet , if you call  `var vc = SearchTableViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)` The outlet **companyName** label is not initialised , therefore it is nil , therefore accessing **companyName** label causes crash.

But in the first case you are initialising viewController from storyboard which is having **SearchTableViewController** scene contains  **CompanyTableViewCell** with outlet **companyName**  and it is connected to Cell ,hence it is initialised , there fore it works as expected.

Solution is :

1. If your are using storyBoard use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method to initialise viewController(assuming that **SearchTableViewController** has **CompanyTableViewCell** in the storyboard).
2. If you are doing programatically then override  all initialiser method of **CompanyTableViewCell** to create a label and add it to cell.

Answer (score 1):

`cell.companyName` is an implicitly unwrapped optional and it is `nil` (not a `UILabel`)

The error is saying that you can't assign to `(nil).text`

I don't know how your custom cell works but you may be able to assign a `UILabel` instance to `cell.companyName`